# List of currently displayed rows in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I have a `List(Of String)` which I want to contain a list of primary keys based on if the associated row in `dgv` is displayed.

I need to both add and remove values from the list as they are displayed/hidden.

Currently I am doing this:

```
Private Sub dgv_RowStateChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs) Handles dgv.RowStateChanged

    If e.StateChanged = DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed Then
        If Not VisibleRows.Contains(e.Row.Cells("SQ").Value.ToString) Then
           VisibleRows.Add(e.Row.Cells("SQ").Value.ToString)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

However this will just add an item to my list when a new row is displayed without removing the hidden row's primary keys.

I can remove a value from the list using `VisibleRows.Remove(e.Row.Cells("SQ").Value.ToString)` however I don't know how to identify that a row is no longer displayed.

What is the result of e.StateChanged when a row is no longer displayed?

Comment: is there a potential for this to be a very large list of items in the datagridview?

Comment: Not especially. The DataGridView could have several thousand rows, but they could only be ~30 or so displayed on someone's screen at any one time. Unless they had a 4k screen or something, I suppose...

Comment: Then I would just clear the list each time and for each through the dgv and rebuild the list with the invisible row primary keys. How are you un-hiding them? if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: That was my first thought, I might just need to try a few methods and see what works. I'm not hiding or unhiding anything, just getting the cells which are displayed on the screen for use else where in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.

`DataGridViewElementStates` is an enum containing flags. You might want to check for it like this:

```
If e.StateChanged And DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed = DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed Then
    ...
End If
```

I don't know if the event gets triggered for rows that become invisible. But then again, I would not want to keep track of such a list of strings. Smells not so well.

Personally (if I really need a list of strings containing the visible items), I would do the following:

- fill the list only when I need it (for example by using a readonly property that refreshes the list if it is invalid).
- invalidate (or simply dispose of) the list in the `dgv_RowStateChanged` event handler (or perhaps in a more appropriate event handler; I would need to check)

Something like this:

```
Private _visibleRows As List(Of String)  'Only use this inside the VisibleRows property and the dgv_RowStateChanged event handler. For all other usage of the list, use the VisibleRows property!

Private ReadOnly Property VisibleRows As List(Of String)
    Get
        If _visibleRows Is Nothing Then
            _visibleRows = New List(Of String)

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
                If row.Displayed Then
                    _visibleRows.Add(row.Cells("SQ").Value.ToString)
                End If
            Next
        End If

        Return _visibleRows
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub dgv_RowStateChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs) Handles dgv.RowStateChanged
    _visibleRows = Nothing
End Sub
```

But it still does not smell right. Depending on the rest of your code, this might also have a dramatically bad performance.

Edit:

You might replace the For-loop in the `VisibleRows` property with the following code:

```
Dim index As Integer = dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex
Dim row = dgv.Rows(index)

While (row.Displayed)
    _visibleRows.Add(row.Cells("SQ").Value.ToString)
    index += 1
    row = dgv.Rows(index)
End While
```

This might be faster...

Edit 2:

The code in my first edit has a bug: you might get an index-out-of-range-exception when you scroll down to the bottom of the datagrid. So you also need to check inside the While-loop if the increased `index` value is valid before you try to fetch that next `row` or exit the loop otherwise. But I'm not going to correct this. I don't like this entire "solution" at all. ;)

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer. This certainly puts me in the right direction for what I initially asked, but you are correct that it's probably not a smart way to doing this. The reason for keeping the list of visible rows (based on the primary key) is so that I can report out to other users if someone else is "looking" at those rows. I'm sure there is a better way of doing this, but I'm trying to avoid requiring a significant behavior change from the end users.

Comment: You're welcome. I understand. Well, I am glad that my contribution was helpful. If this code is really important to you, I can fix that bug in my updated code, but I guess you can fix it yourself too. Should not be very difficult.

Comment: Not to worry, I can fix the bugs, it was the concept I was struggling with. Thanks for your help. :)